# Why I getting always a prompt on a where condition?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to open a report by setting a filter. But it always opens a prompt to enter the filter value, whitch is already defined?

[image]

No Parameters in the query are defined.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSalaryRange", acViewPreview, , "[FamilyCode] = ENS"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does `ENS` come from, what Access is asking about?

If it's a control on a form where your code is being executed from then try this.

In case `FamilyCode` is a numeric field:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSalaryRange", acViewPreview, , "[FamilyCode] = " & ENS.Value`

In case `FamilyCode` is a text field:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "rptSalaryRange", acViewPreview, , "[FamilyCode] = '" & ENS.Value & "'"`

Comment: It is a textfield. I just forgot these ' marks. Oh, this vba is killing me... Thanks for help mate.